# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send') in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to send a message to a specific channel on discord, however gives me this error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')
```

I've entered the correct channel id though, what could be the issue ? Here's my function code and a snapshot :

```
function discordsend(usern)
{ 
    usern="someusername#1234"
    string = "somethingsomething"+usern;
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get('946932969359179786');
    channel.send(string);
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8NSS.png)

Comment: `fetch` returns a promise, so you need to use `|| await client.channels.fetch` instead

Comment: It gives me this then : 
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: Yes, because it needs to be inside an async function so it should be `async function discordsend(...`

Comment: still gives me the same issue..

Comment: You should really do some basic debugging. Have you checked the value of `channel`?

Comment: Try `channel.send?.(string);` If the typings for channels aren't correct, this can potentially bypass the missing send type if there is really a send function

Comment: Finally figured out the issue ! 

The function is actually alright, the issue is that I was calling it before client.login worked and client.once executed, so the client.channels.cache.get was not actually returning any value before channel.send was called !

Answer (score 0):

You should use `client.guilds.cache.get("guild ID").channels.cache.get("channel ID")`

Also use conditional chaining to not get errors if the channel doesn't exist in the first place.